# Minha pesquisa no BD oracle não trás resultado

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net

Tenho um método, usando Ado.Net para trazer informações do BD(Oracle 11g). Há informações na tabela(6 registros) e quando executo pelo `C#` não vem nenhum registro. Veja o código abaixo:

```
public class ConexaoBanco
    {
        string conexao = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FarmExternaConnect"].ConnectionString;
        List<string> listaArquivoFarmExterna = new List<string>();
        public bool CriaConexao()
        {
            OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(conexao);
            conn.Open();

            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = "select path, arquivo from gh_arquivos_farm_externa";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while(dr.Read())
            {
                listaArquivoFarmExterna.Add(dr.ToString());
                //listaArquivoFarmExterna.Add(dr.GetString(1));
            }

            return listaArquivoFarmExterna.Count > 0? true : false;
        } 
    }
```

O mais interessante nisso tudo é a seguinte situação. Quando eu chego nessa linha `OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();` e dou um F10(em modo debug), eu avanço e ao debugar essa linha existe informação(correta), porem se eu debugo a variável `dr` nessa linha `while(dr.Read())`, já diz que:

> A enumeração não gerou resultados

e se eu volto para a linha superior, onde há instantes atr´s havia resultado, tenho a mesma mensagem. Não sei o que tá acontecendo.

Comment: E não dá erro nenhum?

Comment: @Krismorte, fiz uma edição no post original.

Comment: Algum outro comando funciona? Será que a conexão está sendo realizada de verdade. Tenta por uma try/catch pra ver se alguma exceção ta sendo gerada.

Answer (score 0):

Matei o problema. Quando eu debugava, eu acionava a leitura e como ele não volta para ler a fetch novamente, ao chegar no while já chegava sem informações. Foi falha minha